# how to delete all list indexes and new ones programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm using OOTB community site in my project, this template have a **Discussions List** by default with a lot of index columns, I need to delete all these indexes and and new ones programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `Indexed` boolean property of `SPField` for adding/deleting index on a column. Example code to delete the existing Indexes:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
    SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
    SPList list = root.Lists["L2"];
    SPFieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++ )
    {
        SPField field = fields[i];
        if (field.Indexed)
        {
            field.Indexed = false;
            field.Update();
        }
    }                   
}
```

For setting the index, you can reverse the logic.

**UPDATE**
Delete the indexes:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Discussions List"];
SPFieldIndexCollection indexes = list.FieldIndexes;                    
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        var x = indexes[i].Delete();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Some indexes like "Posted By", cannot be deleted as they result in error:

> This lookup field must be indexed because it enforces a relationship
>   behavior.

Create composte index:

```
SPField createdBy = list.Fields["Created By"];
createdBy.Indexed = true;
createdBy.Update();

SPField created = list.Fields["Created"];
created.Indexed = true;
created.Update();

list.FieldIndexes.Add(createdBy, created);
```

Comment: this work with primary field index, but "Discussions List" have index with two fields (e.g. Category, Is Answered), so how I can delete all of theme, ragardless, index is with one or two fields

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't delete from the collection during looping, I suggest the following code:

```
            SPList list = web.Lists["Discussions List"];
            SPFieldIndexCollection indexes = list.FieldIndexes;

            var indexsIDs = new List<Guid>();

            foreach (SPFieldIndex index in list.FieldIndexes)
            {
                indexsIDs.Add(index.Id);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < indexsIDs.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    list.FieldIndexes.Delete(indexsIDs[i]);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
```